# Cant not installed plugin for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, genymotion

i tried to install genymotion for android studio 3.0. But i got this error. How to fix. Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gchDT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the Genymotion plugin for Android Studio

In Android Studio, go to File/Settings (for Windows and Linux) or to Android Studio/Preferences (for Mac OS X)
Select Plugins and click Browse Repositories.
Right-click on Genymotion and click Download and install. To see Genymotion plugin icon, display the toolbar by clicking View > Toolbar.

You can do it through jar file but it is not recommended